# How to mock a web service request defined in controller class?

Tags: java, web-services, junit

I have a function in controller class that calls a Rest Easy web service which returns a response. I need to unit test that particular function.

```
public void createOrderRequest(OrderModel orderModel, ResourceBundle resourceBundle, AspectModel aspectModel) {
    try {
        LOG.debug("Creating order request");
        OrderReq orderRequest = new OrderReq();
        orderRequest.getHeader().setDestination("http://localhost:8080/middleware/ws/services/txn/getReport");
        orderRequest.setUserId("abc");
        OrderResp response = (OrderResp) OrderService.getInstance().getOrderService().sendRequest(orderRequest);
        if (response.getHeader().getErrorCode() == ErrorCode.SUCCESS.getErrorCode()) {
            LOG.debug("Successfully send order request");
            orderModel.setErrorDescription("Order successfully sent");
            aspectModel.set(orderModel);
        }

    }  catch (Exception ex) {
        LOG.error("Error while sending order request: " + ex.getMessage());            
    }

}
```

I want to mock the order request object `OrderReq` and response object `OrderResp`. My intention is to create mock response for the rest easy web service request. How can I achieve it ?

Comment: Your topic says, you want to mock a service, and later you ask, you want to just mock two objects. Actually what do you want to do? And, for a private method testing in a explicit way is not possible.

Comment: @Maleenc please see my edit. Actually I want to mock the request and response objects and unit test them.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way is to move the object creation into a help method which you can override in a test:

```
public void createOrderRequest(OrderModel orderModel, ResourceBundle resourceBundle, AspectModel aspectModel) {
    try {
        LOG.debug("Creating order request");
        OrderReq orderRequest = createOrderReq();
....
    }
}

/*test*/ OrderReq createOrderReq() { return new OrderReq(); }
```

Using package private (default) visibility, a test can override the method (since they are in the same package).

Alternatively, you can create a factory and inject that.

Comment: how can i create the factory. My intention is to create mock response for the rest easy web service request.

Comment: If you don't know how to use factories, go with the code example above.